# Navbar not displaying correctly in Reactjs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm trying to build a modular react application but have trouble with the navbar, for some reason the navbar is not formatting correctly.

WEbpage:-

[image]

Here is my complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ReactStrap</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
    var Navbar = React.createClass({
      render(){
        return(
          <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="navbar-header">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">ReactStrap</a>
              </div>
              <div id="navbar">
                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li className="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        );
      }
    });

    var Jumbotron = React.createClass({
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
          <div className="jumbotron">
            <div className="container">
              <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
              <p className="lead">This is a Bootstrap theme that uses React.js components</p>
              <p><a className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    var Page = React.createClass({
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <div className="container">
              This is the home page
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
    var Theme = React.createClass({
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Jumbotron />
            <Page />
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <div>
        <Theme />
      </div>,
      document.getElementById('root'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you checked the css for navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bootstrap seem not to be included properly . 
here is a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vaqekan/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ReactStrap</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">react</div>

    <script type="text/babel">
    var Navbar = React.createClass({
      render(){
        return(
          <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="navbar-header">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">ReactStrap</a>
              </div>
              <div id="navbar">
                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li className="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        );
      }
    });

    var Jumbotron = React.createClass({
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
          <div className="jumbotron">
            <div className="container">
              <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
              <p className="lead">This is a Bootstrap theme that uses React.js components</p>
              <p><a className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    var Page = React.createClass({
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <div className="container">
              This is the home page
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
    var Theme = React.createClass({
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Jumbotron />
            <Page />
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <div>
        <Theme />
      </div>,
      document.getElementById('root'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```